# Django: Disable automatic language path prefix

Tags: django, django-urls, django-middleware

I have a Django website with

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

and added middleware:

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
```

Currently the website will add a language prefix (i.e. /en/) to my path in case the prefix is missing.

> example.com/page/
>   (301)=>
>   example.com/en/page/

I want to disable that behavior. If the language prefix is missing in the users URL I want a clean 404.

How can I do that?